# angularjs and Spring MVC framework

Tags: spring, angularjs

I having trouble dealing with `angularjs`.

My code is like this:

$routeProvider

```
.when('/chart/pie',{
    templateUrl : 'chart/pie'
})
```

ChartController

```
public ModelAndView getChart(){
   ModelAndview mv = new ModelAndView();

   mv.setView("chart");

   mv.addObject("user", User);

   return mv;
}
```

chart.html

```
result : {{user}}
```

I would guessed I received  `[ result : {'name': 'haha', 'age' : '17'}]`
but result was: `[result : {{user}} ]`

How can I get the preferred result?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the `User` (not the model and view object), and need to add the `ReponseBody` annotation

```
@ResponseBody
public User getChart(){
    User user = ....
    return user;
}
```

---

Hint: from the Spring point of view, this problem has nothing to to with AngularJs, but sending a JSON response. So if you have more problems, that search for Spring and Json (a simple example can be found [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/)).